# Converting C++/mex to C++ only

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

2 years ago I started writing data processing code in MATLAB and thanks to armadillo I have been able to convert it to a C++/mex file. It has finally all been converted to C++/mex but no longer needs to be mex just C++. So I started writing up the C++ main function and included the header files for the functions I used in the mex version and when I try to compile I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYOMZVI.o: undefined reference to symbol 'mxGetN_800'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/glnxa64//libmx.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

When compiling with Matlab/Mex the command I use is:

```
mex -v COMPFLAGS='$COMPFLAGS /std:c++11' COPTIMFLAGS="-O3 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG" CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fopenmp -march=native" -I/usr/include rcp_adp.cpp -I/usr/include ini.c -I/usr/include cpp/INIReader.cpp -L/lib64 -lgomp -larmadillo -lmwlapack -lmwblas -lfftw3_omp -lfftw3 -lm
```

and my C++ test function compile:

```
g++ test.cpp -O3 -fopenmp -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/glnxa64/ -lgomp -larmadillo -lmwlapack -lmwblas -lfftw3_omp -lfftw3 -lm
```

It's been probably about 5 years since I've compiled C/C++ from terminal and not from MATLAB for mex so I might be missing something quite simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `mx...` functions are MATLAB functions, working in MATLAB arrays. If you’re not making a MEX-file, you likely should remove those function calls.

Comment: I am generating a mat file as the finale step which should be possible by c++ program

Comment: In that case you'll have to add the appropriate MATLAB libraries to your build command. Probably something like `-lmx`. See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/mat-file-library-and-include-files.html

Comment: And according to [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/what-you-need-to-build-custom-applications.html), MathWorks recommends that you use `mex -client ...` to build your program.

Comment: -client engine worked kinda, it now compiles but when I try to run it I get 
`error while loading shared libraries: libmx.so`

Comment: Add the directory where `libmx.so` is in to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running your program. Probably something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;/usr/local/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/glnxa64/ test`

Comment: libmx.so is a MATLAB API library. If you are creating standalone C/C++ code that doesn't use the MATLAB API library then you shouldn't need this file in your build.